# Stuck on level 40 of logical puzzle game

Tags: flow-fit-sudoku

The mobile game "Flow Fit Sudoku" is a puzzle game with simple rules similar to regular sudoku - there can only be one of each number per row/column.

So far I have succeeded to solve every board by logical deduction and not by trial & error (I also skipped all the easy/medium packages).

Now I am stuck on Lvl 40 of the "Wild spots" extreme pack. It comes with a special rule:

Each one of the red tiles contains a `?` which means it can be any number. Each of the `?` can represent 2 different numbers, e.g. it could be a `2` for the column, but a `5` for the row.

My usual methods of first arranging the tiles like they are on the board to possibly find a bijective valid combination failed so far.

My deductions so far are:

The first tile I could deduce so far without a doubt is that the green `3 4` tile has to be in one of the places in the left-most column. The orange tiles in the leftmost column have to be one of the `8 6` and either `2 7` or `2 5` (leaving the green `1 5` or `1 7`).

The 3 missing numbers are `1`, `2` and `4`.

With this info, I can nail down one red and one green tile to their exact spots. However, after that, I again am stuck.

Any help is appreciated! Please do **not** post the solved puzzle, but rather the logical reasoning that I am missing at the moment to find the next tiles to place unambiguously.

[image: Flow Fit Sudoku - Wild Spots pack - Level 40]

Comment: I get stuck about the same point as you... This may be more appropriate for the puzzles exchange: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/. Even though it is a video game, your question is asking specifically for the logic of how to progress in your current state of the puzzle, not a straight answer. Not to denigrate anyone here, but the puzzlers may be more equipped to know how (if) there is a purely logical way to move forward with what you've deduced so far.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will do this should another question arise! I wasn't aware of puzzling.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Hint: One of the brown triples has a clear position on the board based on excluded numbers in a column.

> 458 has an 8, 247 has a 4, 781 has an 8 in the column. So you must use 363 in the brown gap below the already filled in red entry.

Comment: That answer was actually perfect, thanks a lot. I was stuck on that level for so long that I kind of lost steam after I figured out, how to place the red/green tiles (I wasn't sure, if that deduction was correct in the first place).